# AdMob EARNINGS (USD) value is not the real value

Tags: adsense-api

We use the following AdSense Management API to get AdMob revenue, but the revenue we get from is 1/100 smaller than the actual value on AdMob dashboard.
This makes me think that there is some setting we need to consider in the API request?

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/reports/generate

```
response = ad_sense.generate_report(date.to_s, date.to_s,
 metric: %w[CLICKS EARNINGS INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS],
 dimension: %w[APP_ID APP_PLATFORM AD_UNIT_NAME AD_UNIT_ID DATE COUNTRY_CODE],
 currency: 'USD',
 use_timezone_reporting: true)
```

Response: $12.87
True value: $1,287

The currency code on the dashboard is USD.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It could depend on the account default setting (I.e., currency). You have mentioned that request and dashboard uses USD, but I think it worth to
check.

To check AdMob's account defaults, you need:

- Login to AdMob UI (admob.google.com);
- Go to Settings -> Account Information;
- Check the default reporting currency.

In case all set correct, you can try an [AdMob API](https://developers.google.com/admob/api/v1/getting-started) to get AdMob related reports. It works well to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave off currency so that the API report will use the account's default. That's worth a shot just to be sure that the currencies are the same.

It's hard for me to compare the two reports since I don't know what parameters are set on the UI report, but I would recommend checking that all the dimensions and filters are the same. Certain dimensions can lead to double-counting report data, like [this example with custom channels](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1703501).

Finally, I would second Maksym's advice to try the new AdMob API for reporting. It's designed to give you reports more in line with the AdMob UI.